# Custom Errorhandler doesn't work on Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, flask

I am deploying my Python app to the web and use Cloud Run from Google for that.
Everything works so far but the `errorhandler` does not.

I use `flask limiter` to limit the requests of a route. By the following code i render a template called `429.html` which should show up for the `429-error`. On my local machine it does actually, on Cloud run I get the basic `flask limiter` page returned.
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ljez.png)

My code for the `errorhandler` is the following:

```
@app.errorhandler(429)
def page_not_found(e):
    # note that we set the 404 status explicitly
    db = onpage_functions.get_stats()
    return render_template('static/429.html', db=db), 429
```

Comment: I closed this because it's not possible to definitively get to the answer you provided from the information which is included in the question at this time (i.e. there's only enough info here to guess, not answer). At a minimum, based on your answer, you need to include enough of the code with the problem to show that the `app.run()` was, in fact, prior to the `@app.errorhandler(429)`. This should be a relatively simple change. Once you [edit] to add that additional code/context your question will be automatically placed in a reopen review queue to be reviewed for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a replica of your case but in my case the custom error handler works. I created this example since cloud shell editor. I share with you my code I hope are helpful for you:

app.py:

```
"""
A sample Hello World server.
"""
import os
import requests
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address
from flask import Flask, render_template

# pylint: disable=C0103
app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(
    app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["2 per minute", "1 per second"],
)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    message = "It's running!"

    """Get Cloud Run environment variables."""
    service = os.environ.get('K_SERVICE', 'Unknown service')
    revision = os.environ.get('K_REVISION', 'Unknown revision')

    return render_template('index.html',
        message=message,
        Service=service,
        Revision=revision)
    

@app.errorhandler(429)
def page_not_foundes(e):
    # note that we set the 429 status explicitly
    return render_template('429.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_port = os.environ.get('PORT', '8080')
    app.run(debug=False, port=server_port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

requeriments.txt:

```
Flask==1.1.2
requests==2.25.1
ptvsd==4.3.2 # Required for debugging.
Flask-Limiter==1.4
```

Custom html was created on directory templates
429.html

```
<h1>MY CUSTOM 429</h1>
```

After I send two request I successfully watch my custom error. I hope my code helps you :D

Answer (score -2):

My code definitly worked, as I figured out after a few days.

The error was, that I placed

```
@app.errorhandler(429)

def page_not_found(e):
    # note that we set the 404 status explicitly
    db = onpage_functions.get_stats()
    return render_template('static/429.html', db=db), 429
```

below the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_port = os.environ.get('PORT', '8080')
    app.run(debug=False, port=server_port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The python syntax goes through the code line by line, so everything placed below the `app.run()` will never be executed.